# How can i use returned value from custom tool in OPENAI Function Agents System Message in Flowise AI

Tags: langchain, flowise

I've developed a custom tool that generates a random word, and I'd like to display this word in a system message.

The behavior I'm looking for is similar to what's shown in the screenshot below.

[Random Word System Message Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN8gh.png)

Could someone please guide me on how to implement this functionality? Specifically, I need to know:

- How to pass the randomly generated word to the system message for display.

how can i archive that?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate the random word as part of a regular LLM chain then you may be able to use Prompt Chaining, which is explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLfiNnK4NOM)

If you need to use a tool I am not aware of any way to do this currently. But it seems there may be a [possibility with custom tools](https://github.com/FlowiseAI/Flowise/discussions/1434) that invoke the API and use the chat history.
You may also want to ask your question on the Flowise Github discussions. (where the previous link is linking to)